# Get VM status using Azure Python SDK

Tags: python, azure

I have a list of VMs and I'd like to get each VM's status (ReadyRole/Stopped/StoppedDeallocated) using Azure's Python SDK.

I have done this in a bash terminal using `azure cli` commands and a combination of `grep,tail` and such utils but I'd like to do that in python script using Azure's SDK.

With the help of `azure cli` I run in a shell script `azure vm list` and then `grep` my way to get the status of the VMs.

I've been looking into `servicemanagementservice.py` of Azure SDK but I can't find a function like `get_role_status()`. `list_hosted_services()` and `get_hosted_service_properties` don't seem to provide the info I want, unless I'm missing something.

Can anyone point me towards a solution?

Comment: See if `get_role` (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure/servicemanagement/servicemanagementservice.py#L1226) helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on my experience, we can get every instances status using [Azure REST API.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee460806.aspx)
So Azure SDK for python should have similar method, because the functions in Azure SDK use the same URL as REST API.
I tried to use this method `get_deployment_by_name` to get the instances status:

```
subscription_id = '****-***-***-**'
certificate_path = 'CURRENT_USER\\my\\***'
sms = ServiceManagementService(subscription_id, certificate_path)
result=sms.get_deployment_by_name("your service name","your deployment name")
```

You can get the role list and check the every role property, please see this picture:
[image]

Comment: `result.status` returns `u'Running'` which is not exactly what I want but it does the job, I think. Thank you very much!

Comment: The value of result.status isn't the VM status, it is your host service status. You can get instance status via "instance_status" property.  Please view the image in  update reply