# Azure python sdk - getting the machine state

Tags: python, azure

Using the python api for azure, I want to get the state of one of my machines.

I can't find anywhere to access this information.

Does someone know?

After looking around, I found this:

```
get_with_instance_view(resource_group_name, vm_name)
```

https://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.computemanagement.html#azure.mgmt.compute.computemanagement.VirtualMachineOperations.get_with_instance_view

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that we are using the resource manager ap, which is a year old or so.

Comment: get_with_instance_view(resource_group_name, vm_name, vm_extension_name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new API resource manager
There's a function:

```
get_with_instance_view(resource_group_name, vm_name)
```

It's the same function as get machine, but it also returns an instance view that contains the machine state.

https://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.computemanagement.html#azure.mgmt.compute.computemanagement.VirtualMachineOperations.get_with_instance_view

Answer (score 9):

if you are using the legacy api (this will work for classic virtual machines), use

```
from azure.servicemanagement import ServiceManagementService
sms = ServiceManagementService('your subscription id', 'your-azure-certificate.pem')

your_deployment = sms.get_deployment_by_name('service name', 'deployment name')
for role_instance in your_deployment.role_instance_list:
    print role_instance.instance_name, role_instance.instance_status
```

if you are using the current api (will not work for classic vm's), use

```
from azure.common.credentials import UserPassCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

import retry

credentials = UserPassCredentials('username', 'password')
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, 'your subscription id')

@retry.retry(RuntimeError, tries=3)
def get_vm(resource_group_name, vm_name):
    '''
    you need to retry this just in case the credentials token expires,
    that's where the decorator comes in
    this will return all the data about the virtual machine
    '''
    return compute_client.virtual_machines.get(
        resource_group_name, vm_name, expand='instanceView')

@retry.retry((RuntimeError, IndexError,), tries=-1)
def get_vm_status(resource_group_name, vm_name):
    '''
    this will just return the status of the virtual machine
    sometime the status may be unknown as shown by the azure portal;
    in that case statuses[1] doesn't exist, hence retrying on IndexError
    also, it may take on the order of minutes for the status to become
    available so the decorator will bang on it forever
    '''
    return compute_client.virtual_machines.get(resource_group_name, vm_name, expand='instanceView').instance_view.statuses[1].display_status
```

Comment: for some reason 'instance_view' always None, other params appear correct.

Comment: @AnatoliiChmykhalo In order to have the `instance_view` not None, you need to add `expand='instanceView'` to the `compute_client.virtual_machines.get` call

Comment: For folks still looking at this answer, `retry` has been replaced with `tenacity`.  Be sure to use that instead.  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Azure Cloud Services, you should use the Role Environment API, which provides state information regarding the current instance of your current service instance.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleenvironment.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use this method get_deployment_by_name to get the instances status:

```
subscription_id = '****-***-***-**'
certificate_path = 'CURRENT_USER\\my\\***'
sms = ServiceManagementService(subscription_id, certificate_path)
result=sms.get_deployment_by_name("your service name","your deployment name")
```

You can get instance status via "`instance_status`" property.
Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/31404545/4836342

Comment: Thank you this would be a good answer, but I should have mentioned we are not using the old api.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers the Azure Resource Manager API has an instance view query to show the state of running VMs.

The documentation listing for this is here: [VirtualMachineOperations.get_with_instance_view()](https://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/azure.mgmt.compute.computemanagement.html#azure.mgmt.compute.computemanagement.VirtualMachineOperations.get_with_instance_view)

Typical code to get the status of a VM is something like this:

```
resource_group = "myResourceGroup"
vm_name = "myVMName"
creds = azure.mgmt.common.SubscriptionCloudCredentials(…)
compute_client = azure.mgmt.compute.ComputeManagementClient(creds)
vm = compute_client.virtual_machines.get_with_instance_view(resource_group, vm_name).virtual_machine

# Index 0 is the ProvisioningState, index 1 is the Instance PowerState, display_status will typically be "VM running, VM stopped, etc.
vm_status = vm.instance_view.statuses[1].display_status
```

Answer (score 0):

- There is no direct way to get the state of a virtual machine while listing them.
- But, we can list out the vms by looping into them to get the `instance_view` of a machine and grab its power state.
- In the code block below, I am doing the same and dumping the values into a `.csv` file to make a report.

```
import csv
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient


def get_credentials():
    subscription_id = "*******************************"
    credential = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
        client_id="*******************************",
        secret="*******************************",
        tenant="*******************************"
    )
    return credential, subscription_id


credentials, subscription_id = get_credentials()

# Initializing compute client with the credentials
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

resource_group_name = "**************"
json_list = []
json_object = {"Vm_name": "", "Vm_state": "", "Resource_group": resource_group_name}

# listing out the virtual machine names
vm_list = compute_client.virtual_machines.list(resource_group_name=resource_group_name)

# looping inside the list of virtual machines, to grab the state of each machine
for i in vm_list:
    vm_state = compute_client.virtual_machines.instance_view(resource_group_name=resource_group_name, vm_name=i.name)
    json_object["Vm_name"] = i.name
    json_object["Vm_state"] = vm_state.statuses[1].code
    json_list.append(json_object)

csv_columns = ["Vm_name", "Vm_state", "Resource_group"]
f = open("vm_state.csv", 'w+')
csv_file = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=csv_columns)
csv_file.writeheader()
for i in json_list:
    csv_file.writerow(i)
```

- To grab the state of a single virtual machine, where you know its `resource_group_name` and `vm_name`, just use the block below.

```
vm_state = compute_client.virtual_machines.instance_view(resource_group_name="foo_rg_name", vm_name="foo_vm_name")
power_state = vm_state.statuses[1].code
print(power_state)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the new API reference, this worked for me

```
vm_status = compute_client.virtual_machines.instance_view(GROUP_NAME, VM_NAME).statuses[1].code
```

it will return any one of these states, based on the current state

```
"PowerState/stopped", "PowerState/running","PowerState/stopping", "PowerState/starting"
```